# How to create an object that calls delegate methods from another class?

Tags: java, oop, object, delegation

I'm trying to program a class following the UML below to demonstrate a hierarchy but when I try to create an M1AbramsTank the constructor doesn't accept an engine type of SteamEngine.

The requirment was that `The constructor of ArmouredFightingVehicle should accept as a parameter an
instance of PoweredVehicle` which I have added but then I can't specify the type of engine.

The error is `The constructor M1AbramsTank(SteamEngine) is undefined`

The reason is because the constructor of M1Abrams tank takes a type of PoweredVechicle, but how can I specify what engine the object takes?

[image: uml hierarchy]

The `SteamEngine` class and `Engine` interface it implements:

```
public class SteamEngine implements Engine {


    //instance variables
    private int speed;



    public SteamEngine(int speed) {

        this.speed = speed;
    }


    public void setSpeed(int speed) {
        this.speed = speed;
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Steam engine Started:"); 


    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Steam engine Started:"); 


    }

    @Override
    public void throttle(int power) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        speed += power;


    }

    @Override
    public int getSpeed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return speed;
    }

}
```

The `PoweredVechicle` class:

public class PoweredVehicle  {

```
Engine engine;

public PoweredVehicle(Engine engine) {
    super();
    this.engine = engine;
}

public Engine getEngine() {
    return engine;
}


public void  Drive(){


    System.out.println("Generic Driving");

}

public void setEngine(Engine engine) {
    this.engine = engine;
}

public void stop() {
    engine.stop();
}

public void start() {
    engine.start();
}

public void throttle(int power) {
    engine.throttle(power);
}

public int getSpeed() {
    return engine.getSpeed();
}
```

}

`ArmouredVechicle` takes an instance of `PoweredVechicle` as specified to delegate it's methods:

```
public class ArmouredFightingVehicle  {

    PoweredVehicle poweredvechicle;

    public ArmouredFightingVehicle(PoweredVehicle poweredvechicle) {
        super();
        this.poweredvechicle = poweredvechicle;
    }



    public void Drive() {
        poweredvechicle.Drive();
        System.out.println("Armoured vehicle driving..");
    }



    public Engine getEngine() {
        return poweredvechicle.getEngine();
    }

    public void Fight() {
        System.out.println("bang bang!");
    }

    public void setEngine(Engine engine) {
        poweredvechicle.setEngine(engine);
    }

    public void stop() {
        poweredvechicle.stop();
    }

    public void start() {
        poweredvechicle.start();
    }

    public void throttle(int power) {
        poweredvechicle.throttle(power);
    }

    public int getSpeed() {
        return poweredvechicle.getSpeed();
    }

    public String toString() {
        return poweredvechicle.toString();
    }


}
```

The `M1AbramsTank` class:

```
public class M1AbramsTank extends ArmouredFightingVehicle{



    public M1AbramsTank(PoweredVehicle poweredvechicle) {
        super(poweredvechicle);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    @Override
    public void Fight() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("M1 fighting..");

    }


}
```

I try to create a `M1AbramsTank` object in the `Runner` class:

```
M1AbramsTank tank1 = new M1AbramsTank(new SteamEngine(100));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
M1AbramsTank tank1 = new M1AbramsTank(new PoweredVehicle(new SteamEngine(100)));
```

Comment: Is there a way I could set up the classes so that the type of engine doesn't need to be specified when creating an object of the vehicle? Or is this the correct way in which to create the object according to the UML?

Comment: What you could do is create an overloaded constructor in the PoweredVehicle i.e. `PoweredVehicle(){super(); this.engine = new SteamEngine(100);}` <- this basically means that if you don't specify an engine (like your original tank1 decleration), then it will create a default engine. However, the problem with this is that it will always create a steam engines for all `poweredVehicles` that have no engine specified. So the code above, is the correct way.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, how could I create a list of the tank objects?

Comment: `List<ArmouredFightingVehicle> tanks = new ArrayList<ArmouredFightingVehicle>();` - You will need to import `java.util.*;`

And then you will be able to add any type of tank and iterate through them using an advanced for loop